# Issue pre-loading an image from cache in Firefox or Edge

Tags: javascript, css, image, caching

I have a web page which changes the `background-image` url of an element when it is moused-over (using the `:hover` css pseudo-class).

```
.myClass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("a-icon.png");
  background-size: 100px;
}

.myClass:hover {
  background-image: url("b-icon.png");
}
```

In order to avoid a flicker while the browser fetches the 'hot' image for the first time, I use the following JavaScript code to pre-load the image:

```
(new Image()).src = hotImgUrl;
```

This works with Firefox & Edge *if they don't already have a cached version of the image* (i.e. on first visit).
But if you reload the page once the browser has cached the image, it no longer works and you get a flicker as you mouse over the image.

Chrome & Safari don't have this issue.

I have created an example below, which shows the issue.

```js
//pre-load hot image:
(new Image()).src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-b-icon.png";
```

```css
.myClass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-a-icon.png');
  background-size: 100px;
}
.myClass:hover {
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-b-icon.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Is this a Firefox/Edge bug? Or am I going about this in the wrong way? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
//pre-load hot image:
(new Image()).src = "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-b-icon.png";
```

```css
.myClass {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-a-icon.png');
  background-size: 100px;
}

.myClass:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display:block;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background-size: 100px;
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-b-icon.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass"></div>
```

Not really sure that it will help, but at least try.

Comment: Thank you, Alex - this actually works very well. However, there are issues if the 'hot' image contains alpha sections - you will see the image underneath through the alpha sections.

Answer (score 1):

You can unify 2 pics as 1 pic and can change just background-position. So pic loads when page is opened.

```css
div{
background:url("http://www.csstr.com/3.png");
  width:100px;
  height:95px;
  
  background-position:0 center;
}

div:hover{

  background-position:100px center;

}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks u238 - this is a good solution, but unfortunately won't work for me as I need to use 2 separate images. It is for use by a component which allows you to specify a separate image for the 'hot' state.

Answer (score 1):

So what about this one? 2 pics are loaded when page is opened, we need to just set z-indexes.

```css
div {

position:relative;
  
}


img {

  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;

}

#pic1{

z-index:50;

}

#pic2{
  z-index:40;
}

div:hover #pic2{

z-index:55;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
  
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-a-icon.png" id="pic1"/>
  
  <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconexpo/speech-balloon-orange/128/speech-balloon-orange-b-icon.png" id="pic2"/>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks again! This is an improvement for my use case, but it suffers from the same niggle as Alex's answer - alpha in the 'hot' icons will allow the base image to show through.

Comment: I'm an idiot - I could just replace z-index with visibility, and this would work. It means I'd have to refactor the way my component works, but this would solve my issue. I'm hesitant to accept this as the answer as it stands, but if you could edit your answer to add a note about using visibility I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: it's not important if you accept my answer , If you have found the solution. By the way if pics have same size no need to change visibility, z-index will work. Anyway as I said If you find your solution, that's the point.

Comment: z-index will only work if the image is completely opaque, I believe? E.g. edit your code to give #pic2 an opacity of 0.5 to see what I mean.

Comment: I think no. z-index sets stack order of elements. I mean, in the example, there are 2 pics these have completely same size. One of them has bigger z-index therefore it is located in foreground so we can see this one, and the other one back of first one, so we can't see it.